# List Comprehension Check for strings and Give a custom printed error

Tags: python

I need to check if the list contain a string or letter instead of number. The code give me a custom printed error for e.g print(list contain letter try again)

What I've Tried so far

here are two list of mine

```
p=[4,8,9,5,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,3,'a']
b=[8,10,12,6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,19,13,17,14,13,5]
```

What my code needs to check is that if one of both list contain a variable or are not of same length it gives me custom printed error:

```
if len(p) != len(b) or (Check for string):
    print('The length is not equal')
else:
    print([(p[i] ** 2 + b[i] ** 2) ** 1 / 2 for i in range(len(p))])
```

`.isdigit` or `isalpha` doesnot work on lists. So what is the simplest way to check if list contain a str it works with my if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking that both p and b (`p + b`) contain integers only, using the [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) keyword :

```
In [68]: p=[4,8,9,5,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,3,'a']
    ...: b=[8,10,12,6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,19,13,17,14,13,5]
    ...: 

In [69]: if len(p) != len(b):
    ...:     print('The length is not equal')
    ...: elif any(type(ch) != int for ch in p+b):
    ...:     print('Invalid characters found')
    ...: else:
    ...:     print([(p[i] ** 2 + b[i] ** 2) ** 1 / 2 for i in range(len(p))])
    ...:
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplest Solution. You are great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(type(a) == str for a in p):
```

The `any` function does an `or` on the items in the given iterable.  The `and` version is named `all`.

Comment: Why the quotes on `"str"`?